# Can an iPhone/Android app have access to microphone during phone calls?

Tags: iphone, android

I'm wondering if it's possible to record phone calls via apps. (changing voice pitch and etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android can access the microphone. There are apps in the Android Market that record phone calls. I am not sure if you can change the stream without root access.

iPhone - this is completely out - this is all private API and will cause your app to be rejected.